# Django - filtering queryset with optional FormFields

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model:

```
class House(models.Model):
    (...)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    area = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
```

And I have a Form for searching of Houses:

```
class SearchHouseForm(forms.Form):
    price_min = forms.DecimalField(required=False, initial=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    price_max = forms.DecimalField(required=False, initial=999999, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
```

And the view function:

```
def search_for_houses(request):
    queryset = House.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'GET' and 'search-submit-button' in request.GET:
        form = SearchHouseForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                price__lte = form.cleaned_data['price_max'],
                price__gte = form.cleaned_data['price_min']
            )
    else:
        (...)
    return render(request, template, {'house_list': queryset, 'form': form})
```

I have a problem with the `.filter()`-ing. I want to apply the filter if and only if the user provides any value in the form field. If the `price_max` field is left blank, only the `price__gte = form.cleaned_data['price_min']` should be applied. If both `price_max` and `price_min` are left blank, all `House` objects should be returned. Currently I get `ValueError Cannot use None as a query value`

Is there a clean way to do that? The only thing I can think of is a long list of `if` statements for all such optional fields:

```
if form.cleaned_data['price_max'] is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter((...))
if form.cleaned_data['price_min'] is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter((...))
(...)
```

This does not seem as a good idea, especially if I want to apply multitude of such optional filtering fields.

Comment: In the case of just two filters, I would go ahead as you propose and just use `if ...` conditions. But if you want to build more complex queries in the future, consider using `Q` objects. There's a good [blog post](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/) here that shows some ways. You could for example create a dict of filters, and loop through your fields and add the Q-filter if the value of the field is filled.

Comment: @dirkgroten this should be the answer - thanks, I'll work it out this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of just two filters, I would go ahead as you propose and just use `if ...` conditions.

But if you want to build more complex queries in the future, consider using `Q` objects. There's a good blog post [here](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/) that shows some examples. You could for example create a dict of filters, and loop through your fields and add the Q-filter if the value of the field is filled.

Something in this direction:

```py
queries = {'price_max': "price__lte", 'price_min': "price__gte"}
predicates = []
for field, value in cleaned_data.items():
    if value and field in queries:
        predicates.append((queries[field], value))
q_list = [Q(x) for x in predicates]
queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

Not very sure, how else you can do it.

```
if form.cleaned_data['price_max']:
    #filtering
if form.cleaned_data['price_min']:
    #filtering
```

Comment: It's a form instance, keys for fields will always be available even though data in not provided.

Comment: It will not raise `KeyError`, but return `None`

Comment: the downvote is because this is not an answer to the question. This answer just repeats what @Fidd was asking, whether there is another way. There is, so saying 'no' isn't the answer.

Comment: If the field isn't displayed in your template (i.e. not posted as empty value), `cleaned_data[key]` will give you a `KeyError`. Agree, this shouldn't happen in most cases but when you re-use forms in more places in your app, it actually might happen.

Comment: @dirkgroten This might lead to a KeyError, only if form.is_valid() returns false. In this case, since this code is executed post the form validity check. This won't raise a KeyError.

Comment: Then yes. Anyway this discussion is not helping the original question.